# Normal approximation and Hoeffding bound

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, asymptotics, normal-approximation, hoeffdings-inequality

Hoeffding bound for any $\epsilon>0$ is:
$$P_F(|\bar{X}_n-\mu(F)|\geq \epsilon)\leq 2 \exp\{-\frac{n\epsilon^2}{2}\}=h(\sqrt{n}\epsilon)$$ wherever $|X|<1$.

Now I want to have a comparison between this normal approximation and Hoeffding bound. I read that the normal approximation $2\Phi(\frac{\sqrt{n}\epsilon}{\sigma})-1$ gives lower results than $h$ in tails if $P(|X|\leq 1)=1$ because, if $\sigma^2\leq 1$, $1-\Phi(t)\sim\phi(t)/t$ as $t\rightarrow\infty$. I have a bit difficulty in understanding and also verifying this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you show $1-\Phi(t)\leq \phi(t)/t$, which is enough in your problem

$$1-\Phi(t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_t^\infty e^{-x^2/2}\,dx$$
Now
$$\int_t^\infty e^{-x^2/2}\,dx=\frac{\int_t^\infty te^{-x^2/2}\,dx}{t}<\frac{\int_t^\infty xe^{-x^2/2}\,dx}{t}$$
and the integrand is minus the derivative of $\exp(-x^2/2)$, so the integral is $\exp(-t^2/2)$.
Thus we have
$$1-\Phi(t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_t^\infty e^{-x^2/2}\,dx< \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\frac{e^{-t^2/2}}{t}=\phi(t)/t$$

So, yes, the Hoeffding bound of $\exp(-(\sqrt{n}\epsilon)^2/2)$ is larger than the result from the Normal approximation.

That's not particularly surprising. We know the Hoeffding bound won't be *smaller* in any uniform way, because then the Normal approximation would violate it for large enough $n$.